# Core Graphics Opaque type, what are they and how?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, opaque-pointers

I am learning Core Graphics and particularly learning about the CGContextRef.  My question is about the syntax and implementation details (if they are knowable) of opaque data types.  I understand that opaque types such as CGContextRef are references (pointers?) to some underlying structure in memory and it is opaque insofar as the details of this structure are hidden from the developer.

So if I have a variable declared as such: `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` Why does context not require a "*" before it to indicate that this is a reference type/pointer?  What is the semantic significance of this syntactical singularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command-click on the symbol `CGContextRef` to jump to its definition in `CGContext.h` and you'll see why:

```
typedef struct CGContext *CGContextRef;
```

You don't have to put a `*` before your `context` variable because the `*` is part of the `CGContextRef` type definition.